# Including not working , is it too many includes?

Tags: php, html

Hi StackOverFlow members.

I need a favor regarding my programming script.

I'm stunned trying out different various ways to make my code more simpler.

Before I tried to make things simpler . The code works great and it able to do the function.

Here goes:

Detection PHP which worked on a HTML previously before I tried to tweak it a little:

```
<?php
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header('Location: http://facebook.com');
    exit(0);
}
?>

<b> Testing / This is not a supported page for mobile </b>
```

This code works like a charm. When I'd use the browser to access the following page.
It shows me the message "Testing / This is not a supported page for mobile ".

When I'd used a mobile phone to access it , it works like a charm and redirect me back to Facebook.

So this is the new problem that I faced .
I just removed the PHP from the HTML and put it in a file called "detection.php"

```
<?php
include 'detection.php';    
?>

<b> hello </b>
<p> testing on anarchy </p>
```

But this time , when I used the web browser to access the site , it showed me the message 
"Testing on anarchy" and when I used the mobile as well. It still redirect me to the same page 
"Testing on anarchy".

How do we make it in a way where you just need to include the PHP files on the HTML header rather than writing the PHP code on the HTML page.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm am quite sure that your file isn't included... try echoing something from the included file...

Comment: check the path is correct or not.. or if it is on linux then permission is bigg issue

Comment: change include to require. Than the error msg will tell weather your file is included or not. Thanks

Comment: @PhilipG , still no luck.
I just added a line between the $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
echo 'this is testing mobile development'
It's not appearing either.

Comment: @manojdhiman , if i require via root?

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 , No luck even when I changed the code . It still shows as normal as if there's no error and coding issues.

Comment: that is probably due to syntax error, since you cant just put <br> between php code without echoing och print it. You need to do something like "echo 'Testing echo';"  in detection.php and see what pops up

Comment: are you using linux???

Comment: I tested this using the latest version of mobiledetect I downloaded from this site: http://mobiledetect.net/ 

I created a detection.php just as you did file. Actually I copied and pasted your code. 

It worked perfectly, I tested on a android and iphone and was redirecting to facebook in both cases. 

Make sure you are including the file correctly, if it is not in another folder. 

Note: Tested on PHP5.3 and php5.4

Comment: @PhilipG, Oh i dont mix HTML and PHP code together.
I tried doing this <?php
echo "testing on mobile development";
?>

Then in the HTML i just include the detection.php yet no luck.

Comment: @manojdhiman, yes sir.

Comment: if there is no error after using require. and your error log is on. any way i assumed even your error log is off. Your rest of the script will not work. if the path is wrong. So trust me mistake is some where else. you are doing mistake some where else. You are including it fine. @PhilipG where did he put <br> in php tag?

Comment: what is the file permission you have created??there should be execution permission for all

Comment: He vrote that in a comment!

Comment: try adding this code at the top of the main file to force the display of errors (maybe your apache is configured not to display errors): 
<? php 
ini_set ('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting (~ 0); 
?>

Comment: @manojdhiman php files should NOT have exection permission for all. Safest in my opinon is: chmod 644, wich give user read and write permission and group only read.

Comment: @PhilipG may be i am wrong can you just copy and paste that comment. i cant see. Thanks

Comment: @PhilipG yes sorry .. not execution but should be readable ..

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 , error log 0 .. :( this is going to be hard for me.

Comment: @manojdhiman , 777 all permission granted.

Comment: @DanielLima , i'll attach the code in the detection.php and post back the result.

Comment: can you check with the echoing on the detection.php ??

Comment: @DanielLima , no luck. Nothing happens , it just refresh the page..
But previously when I've included the php file to the header it works only when I just make it into 2 seperate files which making it hard to work.

Comment: @manojdhiman , this is the new detection.php i set it "<?php
echo "This is awesome ";
?>"

and the result is when i include it on a HTML header ..

still the same.
It just show
 hello 
 testing on anarchy.
The echo is not echoing :( damn.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. Here is the proof that your code works: 
http://avalone.com.br/test/mobiledetect/ using version 2.8.3 of Mobile Detect

Comment: your include function is not getting the file detection.php , i think

try if(file_exists('detection.php')); to chck is it getting the file on the page

Comment: @DanielLima , okay now that's super weird.
When on my mobile your page redirect to facebook.
But on mine it didn't..

I'm getting confused. 
My PHP in the server is 5.3

Comment: your problem is super weird. One nut job already given you down vote. For no apparent reason. but look @DanielLima is saying the code work. and it work for you before as well. You are missing some thing. which you dont know

Comment: @DanielLima no i am sure he is getting it file. cause he uses required.

Comment: @jaySuriyaa add this line error_reporting(E_ALL); may be it will give you some thing?? may be require is not what i think it is. Just use error_reporting(E_ALL); in the file where you are inluding the file

Comment: Do you want me to upload a zip file with my version of your code working? So you can test it?

Comment: @DanielLima yes please

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 , i guess he doesn't know the problem i faced :(

Comment: @DanielLima do this please i really want to know whats the problem here

Comment: Here is it: http://avalone.com.br/test/mobiledetect/mobiledetect.zip

Comment: @jaysuriya as i said before he was a nut job. you does have a genuine problem. If people cant solve it does not mean they should downvote yor question. dont worry here we go. i solved it.

Comment: @DanielLima , You've done the best job entirely.
But I think I'm going to stick with the old script of mine.
I think it has to do with my server linux because there's no way there's an error in that following code lol and yet it gives a different reading.

Thus i really appreciate for your help !!
I wish you could give me the link under a comment so I could up your rep.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using: you have to use the brackets ('page');, and you should not repeat any code as you are already calling the code from another page, so all you add is:

```
    <?php 
    include('Mobile_Detect.php');
    ?>
```

and on the mobile_detect.php page add:

```
<?php
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header('Location: http://facebook.com');
    exit(0);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use "require" instead of "include".
"require" throws a Fatal Error if the function doesn't find the file, and the script is halted.
"include" throws a Warning if the function doesn't find the file and the script continue to run, which means that you might not notice this bug if you turned off the PHP errors.

Also rely on "require_once" to avoid problems such as "Cannot redeclare function" or "Cannot redeclare constant" etc.

Also, if you're using "header()" you need to make sure you're not using "print" or "echo" prior to the "header" function. Otherwise, you'll get the "headers already sent" error.

To debug your problem, you should use "require_once" and then you should check if it fails. If it fails, then you probably have a problem with your path.